# CSS Grid: Using ::after Underline Effect to Fit Grid Items

Tags: html, css

I'm using the `::after` pseudo selector to create an underline animation under the navigation items. The problem I'm having is that the width doesn't fit the child element (a tag), but the entire width of the grid cell. The ideal scenario is that the animation would stop when it reached the end of the word, while still keeping the original position in the grid cell.

I've tried to specify to the a-tag by using the CSS selector (`#nav-bar li a::after`) but this didn't work, I've also tried to make the `::after` be an absolute element, this just causes the same problem.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  margin: 2rem 0 4rem 0;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-align: left;
}

#nav-bar {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 12.5%) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2rem;
}

#nav-bar li {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto 0px;
}

#nav-bar li a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

#nav-bar li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  transition: ease-in 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<ul id="nav-bar">
  <li id="home">
    <a href="">
            Home
        </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
            About
        </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
            Services
        </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
            Contact
        </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**strong text**

Comment: display:inline-block to a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add inline-block to the anchor.

```
#nav-bar li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```